How do you negate っこない
I don understand how to negate the grammar point of っこない
I get that you put the verb in the ますstem before っこない
Like in the example
泳げっこない
--> There is no way I can swim
But what if I've always been living near the seaside so "There is no way I can NOT swim"
How do I negate the verb before っこない
Or for example
I am a girl who is talking with a guy about random period's emotion. Of course you, being a man, can't understand me because we are talking about period, so I say:
あんたなんかに私の気持ちなんてわかりっこない。
But what if I am talking to a girl, and I wanted to say something like "There is no way you can NOT understand me"

verb in the "can't" form (negative of 可能形) + はず + (optional が or は) ない; i.e.: 泳げないはずない

Or わけ. There is no way I cannot swim. 泳げないわけない
